# Finding the intersection of a line and hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Taking the hyperplane
P = $\{ $x$ :3x^1-3x^2-3x^3-x^4=0\}$
and
the line $t(e_1-e_2)+(1-t)e_4$

I do not know how to solve for t, where t is the intersection of the two.
This is problem 2b from Fleming's Functions of Several Variables.
I am self-studying.

There isn't any point within the book that prepares one for this problem. The method I know for solving this type of problem isn't useful for this version see Lang's (Intro)/Linear Algebra. e.g., (X-Q) $\cdot$ N = O
where N is the normal and Q is some point in the plane and we have the parametric line X=P+tA for some point on the line P, and the line is in the direction of the vector A, for all t.
When trying to use this method of solution I run into the issue of the parametric line and its original counterpart and failure during conversion.

Could you please offer hints as to where to start because I do not think I am doing this the most effective way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming $\;e_i\;$ are the canonical basis elements, the line is:

$$\ell :\;\;t(e_1-e_2)+(1-t)e_4=\left\{\,(t\,,\,-t\,,\,0\,,\,1-t)\,:\;\;t\in\Bbb R\right\}$$

An element in $\;\ell\;$ is also an element in $\;P\;$ iff

$$3t+3t-3\cdot0-(1-t)=0\iff7t=1\iff t=\frac17$$

and thus the intersection is at the point

$$\left(\frac17\,,\,-\frac17\,,\,0\,,\,\frac67\right)$$